# ZF2 ZendSkeleton why using '__NAMESPACE__' key in default route?

Tags: namespaces, routes, zend-framework2

in ZF2 skeleton, router configuration uses a key :

```
'__NAMESPACE__'
```

precisely :

```
'__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
```

cf: 
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#l32

We tried in our modules router config to use without quote:

```
__NAMESPACE__ => 'Application\Controller',
```

but it seems to break configuration.

why do we use quote instead of

```
 __NAMESPACE__
```

to get its value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because by default, config files hasn't namespace declared. Config parser can read string

> `'__NAMESPACE__'`

and determine correctly the namespace.

If you want to use it without quotes, you can declare in your config file :

```
namespace Application;
```

and use `__NAMESPACE__` without quote.

That's why you can see sometimes in tutorials for Doctrine config's sample like :

```
    'doctrine'        => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'application_entity' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'paths' => __DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity',
        ),
        'orm_default'  => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => 'application_entity',
            )
        )
    )
),
```

Comment: I now understand that we precise which namespace to use for the default route.
That is why whe use :

     `'__NAMESPACE__'` as key and not its value 

Thank you :-)